# Meaning of streak clear down in football (soccer) context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "streak clear down" mean in football (soccer) context?

United **streak clear down** the other end and Luiz slips to allow Welbeck through. He passes for Van Persie and the Dutchman can't make up his mind and the chance is gone.

Comment: The players make a run all the way along the pitch. See [streak](https://www.lexico.com/definition/streak) Verb 2: Move very fast in a specified direction.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks. What does "clear" mean there?

Comment: Streak: move fast. Clear: unopposed. Down: a direction.

Comment: [Clear](https://www.lexico.com/definition/clear): *Free of any obstructions or unwanted objects.*